# changing element in list within a list changes whole column - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So im trying to get a paintboard like a coordinate system with the width of 10 and height of 5 so it looks like this represented by lists within lists eg [['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'],['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'],['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'],['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x'],['x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x']]

printing it out would look like this

```
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

now I want to change one element in there so it looks like this

```
xxcxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
```

my code:

```
class Paintboard():

    def __init__(self, width, height):

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        extra = []
        self.board = []
        for x in range(0, self.width):
            extra.append('x')
        for y in range(0, self.height):
            self.board.append(extra)

    def str(self):

        for x in self.board:
            print(" ".join(x))

        return ""

    def paint(self):

    self.board[0][3] = "c" # here btw x and y are switched cuz of element arrangement in self.board

test = Paintboard(10, 5)
test.paint()
test.str()
```

Instead of just replacing element on [3,0] it actually replaces every element in the column for some reason
output:

```
xxxcxxxxxx
xxxcxxxxxx
xxxcxxxxxx
xxxcxxxxxx
xxxcxxxxxx
```

Ive been trying to find the error for a long time now in my code please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.board.append(extra)
```

This line appends the same object as the row to each column. So if you change the object via one row, all other rows also see the effect.

You could make a copy of the row to append instead.

```
self.board.append(extra.copy())
```

And your code should work

Answer (score 0):

other way: you need to change for loop,

```
class Paintboard():

    def __init__(self, width, height):

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.board = []

        for y in range(0, self.height):
            extra = []
            for x in range(0, self.width):
                extra.append('x')
            self.board.append(extra)

    def str(self):

        for x in self.board:
            print(" ".join(x))

        return ""
```